# Problems showing an input in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

When I click an icon I want to show a bootstrap modal asking to enter some text and a date. I have copied the code from W3Schools and edited to show the form that I need, but when I click the button it shows the labels, the text area but not the input date. When I see the code that it's showing the navigator I can see that the input has style in it. Specifically, it has `display: none`, but I don't know what makes the input has that style. I'm using bootstrap so the function that shows the modal is native from bootstrap.

I have tried to put the `<input type='date'>` in a `<label>` but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalHitos" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo hito</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="newHito">Hito</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="newHito"></textarea><br>
                    <label for="newDate">Fecha prevista</label>
                    <label><input type="date" id="newDate"></label>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveHito()">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect that when i click the button, it shows the modal with both labels and both inputs (textarea and input date). But it doesn't show the input date.

[image: Image of the modal]

[image: Image of DevTools in Edge]

Comment: It seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xv3bLrt4/

Comment: @Banzay i see it works as expected on that website. Im using Edge to run my web page. There it doesnt show the input.

Comment: it's weird. My Edge shows date input as well

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the navigator? Specifically where you see the `display: none`?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb i see the display: none in DevTools of Edge. Pressing F12. I will edit the post with an image of my navigator

Comment: your code is working fine [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/n2ht4gem/) or do you have any additional css in your page

Comment: I review all the code and the jquery and i saw some old code i don't use now that was hiding all the input type='date' of the page. Thanks for your help anyway! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but i think you have an issue on your css (plugins).If display:none when you inspect the input. You can use above codes to override the style display attribute of your input date.

```
<input type="date" id="newDate" style="display: inline !important;">
```